# Does the CPU of the Raspeberry Pi 3 B+ use the same assembly as other CPUs?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I want to use my Raspeberry Pi to learn how to make operating systems. I know that to make one I need some assembly code for the bootloader so I can call a function in a kernel written in C. Would the ARM CPU of the Pi use the same assembly code for if I was writing an OS for a normal CPU? Would the OS development steps be similar to normal?

Comment: Make an operating system is a totally broad question. The OS of RPi is built based on Unix and has been written with C (kernel side). You can customize the OS by yourself, similar to Desktop PC Unix OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it would be similar but as it goes with kernel development it may differ in the details like (what instructions are supported by raspberry pi3 itself).Having said that be prepared to do a lot of reading of the arm-v8 instruction set and of course operating system concepts if you have not yet.

As a general tip if you are new to kernel development start with a single cpu and once you are confident enough you can start multi core.

Also I will be pointing out few links which are extremely helpful in building operating systems for raspberry pi for beginners

1. **https://github.com/s-matyukevich/raspberry-pi-os**
2. https://github.com/rsta2/circle64
3. https://github.com/LdB-ECM/Raspberry-Pi
4. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums